# Ranking rows skips rank 1

Tags: mysql

I have a table for players:

```
+------------+-----------+
| player_id  |   date    |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 | 27/1/2018 |
|          1 | 27/1/2018 |
|          1 | 27/1/2018 |
|          2 | 27/1/2018 |
|          2 | 27/1/2018 |
|          3 | 27/1/2018 |
+------------+-----------+
```

I'm trying to rank them by the amount of occurrences grouped by the player_id.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT total2.player_id, COUNT(*) + 1 AS rank FROM (
    SELECT player_id, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM players
    GROUP BY player_id
) total2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT player_id, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM players
    GROUP BY player_id
) total3 ON total3.total > total2.total
GROUP BY total2.player_id
```

Result I'm getting:

```
+------------+------+
| player_id  | rank |
+------------+------+
|          2 |    2 |
|          3 |    3 |
+------------+------+
```

Result I'm trying to get:

```
+------------+------+
| player_id  | rank |
+------------+------+
|          1 |    1 |
|          2 |    2 |
|          3 |    3 |
+------------+------+
```

Comment: If you have no PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really have a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

and here's the fiddle

```
SELECT a.player_id, @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number 
FROM (SELECT player_id, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM players
    GROUP BY player_id) a,
(SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
ORDER BY TOTAL desc
```

Comment: That works, but if I do that, ranks will not be the same if 2 or more players have the same amount of occurrences.

Comment: your original query would have had that same problem...try this 2nd one...you might need to add 1 to the row number

Comment: i have an edit...i had to remove the group by on the 2nd query...more edits